# JavaScript MM_MENU doesn't work on IE8 (32bit)

Tags: javascript, menu

Please check
http://mianniu.com/dsun/services.php

Whenever mouse moves over a top menu IE says

> ebpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C) Timestamp:
>   Sat, 20 Nov 2010 07:21:29 UTC
>
> Message: 'undefined' is null or not an
>   object Line: 559 Char: 3 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://mianniu.com/dsun/include/mm_menu.js
>
> Message:
>   'window.ActiveMenu.Menu.hideTimeout'
>   is null or not an object Line: 499
>   Char: 3 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://mianniu.com/dsun/include/mm_menu.js

It works well on Firefox and Chrome. Very confused. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error on line 559 is caused due to your FIND() function returning a DisplayHTMLELementCollection in IE8 -- it has two elements.  This is due to using the document.all collection I believe.  Modify your function like so, or just have FIND return one of the two elements found :

```
function FIND(item) {
 if (document.getElementById) return(document.getElementById(item));
 if( window.mmIsOpera ) return(document.getElementById(item));
 if (document.all) return(document.all[item]);
 return(false);
}
```